# SVG path fill behaviour with arcs

Tags: css, svg

I created an SVG form with one path that has a few lines and then one arc.
The lines and arcs create a form that I'd like to fill with color.

But it's not behaving like I want it to. I'm wondering if there is a css setting I'm missing or whether my approach is simply wrong.

```
<style>
body {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
#path {
    fill: blue;
    stroke: green;
    stroke-width: 4;
    stroke-miterlimit: 10;
}
</style>

<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="500px" height="500px" viewBox="0 0 300 300" xml:space="preserve">
    <path id="path" d="M25,148 L73,147 L150,70 L220,142 L275,140 M25,150 A5,5 0 1,1 275,142"></path>
</svg>
```

Here is a jsfiddle:
[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o8bnjxug/1/)

I want the blue color only inside the shape, but the arc just screws up my whole form.

Is there an easy fix that I'm missing?

I did do some research on it and tried experimenting with the fill-rule property but it didn't change anything.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The triangular cutaway section is being filled in because the elliptical arc and zigzag section are being effectively drawn as separate objects, so the filled part in the cutaway is just part of the arc section.

The easiest way to fix this is to start the path with the elliptical arc segment, then follow that by the polyline data, but in reverse order so you continue around the object in an anticlockwise direction.

Since every additional pair of coordinates following a `M` or `L` instruction is interpreted as an additional line segment, you can make your markup a bit concise by omitting the extra `L`s:

```css
body {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
#path {
    fill: blue;
    stroke: green;
    stroke-width: 4;
    stroke-miterlimit: 10;
}
```

```html
<svg width="500"
     height="500"
     viewBox="0 0 300 300">
    <path id="path" d="M25 150 A5 5 0 1 1 275 142L275 140 220 142 150 70 73 147 25 148Z"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 3):

Path fills get a little confused if you do moves in the middle of your draw. You should be drawing an arc from the end of your fourth line back to your draw-start. Instead you're moving the pen back to your draw-start and then drawing the arc. Moves are treated like a draw for the purpose of filling.

Comment: No worries. Squeamish's answer is far more complete :)

Comment: yes, someone has been going around doing that - I think you need 20k+ rep to do that.

Comment: yeah.., like, why would somebody delete another one's comment of saying thank you? i mean seriously, some people just are bored and then abuse their power here..